# Why does C++17 never move construct with prvalues?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

The [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) says that

> When the initializer is a prvalue, the move constructor call is often optimized out (until C++17) / never made (since C++17).

I have two questions:

1) Does this mean that construction with literals (e.g. integer `10`) will never move construct?

2) What's the reasoning for this rule?

Comment: That quote you quoted continues with `, see copy elision.`

Comment: My first question might be partially covered by `copy elision`, but the second one is not.

Comment: @BM: The reasoning is "copy elision is good". Do you need another reasoning? Why would you *want* to waste runtime performance copying something that doesn't need to be copied?